# admin_enqueue_scripts using hook_suffix vs GET page

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script, admin-menu

My menu code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'waf_admin_menu'); 

function waf_admin_menu(){

    add_menu_page('WordPress Audio Filter', 'WordPress Audio Filter', WAF_CAPABILITY, 'waf_settings', 'waf_settings_page', plugins_url('assets/menu.png', __FILE__));

    add_submenu_page('waf_settings', __('WordPress Audio Filter', WAF_TEXTDOMAIN), esc_html__('Global settings', WAF_TEXTDOMAIN), WAF_CAPABILITY, 'waf_settings');
        
    add_submenu_page('waf_settings', esc_html__('WordPress Audio Filter', WAF_TEXTDOMAIN), esc_html__('Player manager', WAF_TEXTDOMAIN), WAF_CAPABILITY, 'waf_player_manager', 'waf_player_manager_page');  

}
```

I am using following code to detect page and enqueue appropriate assets for my plugin pages:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts');

function my_admin_enqueue_scripts( $hook_suffix ) {

      switch ( $hook_suffix ) {

            case get_plugin_page_hookname( 'waf_settings', 'waf_settings' ):

              
            break;

            case get_plugin_page_hookname( 'waf_player_manager', 'waf_settings' ):

            break;

       }

 }
```

Is this the same as using $_GET['page']?  (without $hook_suffix)

```
function my_admin_enqueue_scripts() {


    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : null;

    if($page && $page == 'waf_settings'){
    


    } 
    else if($page && $page == 'waf_player_manager')){
    


    } 

}
```

Comment: You can use any of that functions, since they both do the same thing - enqueuing your scripts depending on what the current admin page is. It's just that, `$hook_suffix` includes or more precisely, ends with the `$_GET['page']` value, so the first function runs a more specific check - think of it like targeting the same element using the CSS selector `div.foo` vs `div.foo.bar` ..

Comment: But where is the first part of hook_suffix coming from?

Comment: See [`get_plugin_page_hookname()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_page_hookname/), specifically [lines 2077-2086](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1/src/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L2077-L2086).